# How to set the parent directory of the basedir in maven as the basedir of ant?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, ant

**Background :** 
I need to run an ant task in the build.xml file using maven. So I'm using maven-antrun-plugin to do this.

**Question :** 
When I'm reading the basedir in ant (after running pom) it displays as fldr1.fldr2.prjctNm which was it's defualt value (in both echoes). But, I want to set the parent directory path to it. (eg : fldr1.fldr2). How can I do this.

Ant file alone does this because it defines basedir="../ in the  tag.

**pom.xml (location : fldr1.fldr2.prjctNm)**

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.7</version>

            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-cli</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>

                    <configuration>
                        <target>
                            <property name="basedir" value="../" />
                            <echo message="basedir path 1 : ${basedir}"/>
                            <ant antfile="build.xml" target="cleanAll" />
                        </target>
                    </configuration>

                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>

                </execution>
            </executions>

        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

**build.xml (location : fldr1.fldr2.prjctNm)**

```
<project name="RideUtilities" default="cleanAll" basedir="../">

    <target name="cleanAll" depends="all"></target>

    <target name="all" depends="init,build"></target>

    <target name="init">

        <echo message="basedir path 2 : ${basedir}"/>

        <property name="dirs.base" value="${basedir}/RideUtilities" />
        <property name="src" value="${dirs.base}\src" />
        <property name="jarFile" value="RideUtilities.jar" />
    </target>

    <target name="build">
        <echo> ---Building jar files using ${dirs.base} ---- </echo>
    </target>

</project>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure there was enough detail about what exactly you needed, but I was able to get the behavior you wanted with basedir as follows:

**pom.xml**

```
<target>
   <echo message="basedir path 1 : ${basedir}" />
   <ant antfile="build.xml" target="echo-base-dir" inheritAll="false" />
</target>
```

**build.xml**

```
<project name="test" basedir="..">
    <target name="echo-base-dir">
        <echo>base dir=${basedir}</echo>
    </target>
</project>
```

The output was:

```
C:\dev\JavaTests>mvn antrun:run [INFO] Scanning for projects... 
[INFO]
[INFO]
[INFO] Building test Strategy 3.0.7-SNAPSHOT 
[INFO]
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-antrun-plugin:1.7:run (default-cli) @ test-test ---
[INFO] Executing tasks

main:
     [echo] basedir path 1 : C:\dev\JavaTests

echo-base-dir:
     [echo] base dir=C:\dev

[INFO] Executed tasks
[INFO]  
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO]

[INFO] Total time: 1.005s 
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Nov 06 09:59:36 EST 2013 
[INFO] Final Memory: 8M/182M 

C:\dev\JavaTests>
```

The key was obviously the *inheritAll=false*.  But maybe that will mess up your need to reference some of the Maven properties.

Comment: Thank you Sam. It worked for me. But now I'm  getting below error Unable to find a javac compiler; [ERROR] com.sun.tools.javac.Main is not on the classpath. [ERROR] Perhaps JAVA_HOME does not point to the JDK. [ERROR] It is currently set to "/rezsystem/java/jdk1.6.0_21/jre". Now I'm working on it. Checked the bashrc. But it is in there correctly.

Comment: @NamalFernando: `JAVA_HOME=/rezsystem/java/jdk1.6.0_21`, you are pointing to a directory one level too low.  I think that will fix your problem. The `tools.jar` is in the `/rezsystem/java/jdk1.6.0_21/lib` folder.  (The convention is that JAVA_HOME always points to the root of the Java installation.)

Comment: @NamalFernando: why aren't you using Maven to compile?

Comment: As a standard (for versioning control etc) of our company we have converted all the projects to Maven. But I need some of them to be built on the ANT too.